# Automation and remote controlling

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, education, electrical-engineering, experimental-technique

I am very new in the field of experimental physics. I want to pursue research in the condensed matter physics. I have observed that most of the instruments such as lock-in amplifier, digital current and voltage source and many more sophisticated tools in the lab are remotely controlled using computers. Often these interfaces are programmed in Labview, Python, Visual basics, etc.
So, I am very curious to learn how a computer communicates and record the data with various tools.
I would really appreciate if I get some useful references to learn such skills, starting from basics.

**P.S:** I want to learn the basics of controlling instruments so that I can write a script in any programming language as per the convenience.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an electronics question than a physics question. It is also very broad.

In general terms, their are two types of instruments or sensors that can be attached to a computer. An analogue instrument or sensor will communicate with the outside world by sending or receiving variable voltages on its control lines. The computer must convert between these variable voltages and the digital signals that it can process internally. It does this using an [analogue-to-digital converter(ADC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) and/or a [digital-to-analogue converter (DAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter).

More sophisticated instruments or sensors will have their own built in microcontroller and will be controlled digitally, by a sequence of high and low voltages on their control lines. It is simpler for a computer to communicate with these digital devices because it does not have to convert between analogue and digital signals.

One way to gain experience with these techniques is to built your own device using a microcontroller such as an [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) or a [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). There are designs for many DIY projects using these microcontrollers on the internet.